# How to select QTableView left top widget?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtstylesheets

I am using Qt5.5.1 and I would like to know how to select the red area below, using Qt style sheets.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you seen http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtableview ? It says `QTableView QTableCornerButton::section { ... }`